# PostgreSQL Regular Expression - Excluding strings with numbers

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am starting with Postgre Regular Expressions, working on PostgreSQL 8.3 version.

I have a table of records as following:

```
record
-----------
a  
ab
abc  
123abc 
132abc
123ABC  
abc123
4567  
5678
6789
```

I was going through a simple tutorial:
 [www.oreillynet.com](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/databases/2006/02/02/postgresq_regexes.html?page=2).
Everything seemed clear to me until I came to the following query:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE record ~ '[^0-9]';
```

The tutorail says:

> this expression returns strings that don't include digits.

But it returned following output to me:

```
output
------
a
ab
abc
123abc
132abc
123ABC
abc123
```

Can anyone explain me this behaviour, please? I am then struggling with another expression on that site trying to exclude strings that include digits AND lower-case letters in the same string.

Comment: Wrong: it returns strings that contains one or more non-digit character.

Comment: Thanks very much, maybe not very good tutorial.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This command:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE record ~ '[^0-9]';
```

means that in the `record` field there should be at least one non-digit character (this is the meaning of the regex).

If one looks for the records which would include digits and lower-case letter, then I would expect a regex like:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE record ~ '[0-9a-z]';
```

which would return all the records having at least one character which is a digit or lowercase letter.

If you want to get the records which have no digits, then you would have to use the following regex:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE record ~ '^[^0-9]+$';
```

Here, the `^` character outside of square brackets means the beginning of the field, the `$` character means the end of the field, and we require that all characters in between are non-digits. `+` indicates that there should be at least one such characters. If we would also allow empty strings, then the regex would look like `^[^0-9]*$`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Now, everything is clear!

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE record !~ '[0-9]';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'a2' ~ '^[a-z]+$'; --false
select 'a' ~ '^[a-z]+$'; --true
```

`'^[a-z]+$'`  =>  checks only letters from a-z from the beginning(^) till the end of the string (+$)

If you want to check for numbers: `'^[0-9]+$'`

If you want to check for numbers and a character, lets say "." :`'^[0-9\.]+$'` , where "\" is an escape character